# Theorem on Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

So, I'm trying to prove this particular theorem from Vladimir Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I. It's stated as follows:

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$ be functions. Then, $ (g \circ f = e_X) \implies$ (g is surjective) $\land$ (f is injective). $e_X$ is the identity mapping from X to X.

I was wondering if someone could check my proof and see if it works or not.

**Proof**

Let us construct $g \circ f$ as a set. This is done as follows:

$ g \circ f = \{ (x,x) \in X^2 : \exists y \in Y: ((x,y) \in f) \land ((y,x) \in g)\}$

Clearly, there are two statements that are being made here:

$\forall x \in X: \exists y \in Y: (y,x) \in g$

$\forall x \in X: \exists y \in Y: (x,y) \in f$

The first proposition implies that g is surjective, since the definition of surjectivity demands that there exist at least one input for every output.

Now, suppose that f is not injective. Then, the following proposition must be true:

$\exists x_1,x_2 \in X: [(x_1,y) \in f] \land [(x_2,y) \in f] \land (x_1 \neq x_2]$

Thus, there exists a $y \in Y$ such that $(x_1,x_2) \in g \circ f \land x_1 \neq x_2$. This is a contradiction, since $g \circ f$ is the identity mapping. Hence, f must be injective. This completes the proof.

---

Vladimir Zorich does provide a proof in the textbook, by the way, and i do understand that proof. However, the above is just my attempt at proving the theorem before I saw his proof. I'm trying to get into the habit of proving things on my own before seeing the actual proof done by the author.

Comment: The assumption under which you are operating is that $g \circ f = e_X$, which means $g \circ f = \{(x, x) \in X^2\}$, no further subset selection required.

Comment: The second statement you mention is not a reformulation of injectiveness.

Comment: Indeed, that’s part of the definition of a function. It’s the fact that there must exist an output for every input. It’s just reiterating the fact that f is totally-defined, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to show if $(g \circ f)=e_X$ then ($g$ is onto and $f$ is 1-1).

If $x \in X$ then $g(f(x))=x$ by assumption, so $x$ has a pre-image in $Y$ ($f(x)$) and so $g$ is onto.

If $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $$x_1 = g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2)) = x_2$$ and so $f$ is 1-1.

This seems much simpler to me.

Comment: Oof so my proof is incorrect or just unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats your proof is not correct. It’s close to incomprehensible IMO.

Comment: Ahh alright, I’ll work on it. Thanks.

Comment: Uh would you have any tips on how I could make it more comprehensible?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats you seem (but its unclear) to use the same approach I did, but I think my writeup is cleaner. Don’t write these functions as sets, especially not in an analysis book. Just apply basic facts.

Comment: Ahh okay okay. Apologies, I’m sort of still stuck to the habit of writing them as sets. I picked that up from another book that I read. Maybe that’s why it’s unclear.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats That would be OK in a set theory book, for other kinds of problems..

Comment: Ah alright thanks